# Listing MySQL databases on a local XAMPP install

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

I have a local MySQL install via XAMPP, running on OSX. PHPMyAdmin lists the databases that are running under the MySQL install, but when I run

```
mysql > show databases;
```

Only information_schema is listed. What's the best way to go about troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not connecting to **MySQL** with the right credentials.

Try supplying a username/password/host combination that **actually** has permissions to list databases through `show databases` command.

Something like this:

```
$ mysql -u root -h X.Y.Z.A -p
```

Then supply root's password. And I mean MySQL's root, not your **OS X**'s root password.

Comment: In here, just `mysql -u root` was enough. Of course, the root user must have no password.